# Is there any way to know if a particular local notification has been delivered? (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, notifications

Is there any way to know if a local notification has been delivered so that I can change UI based on it.
For example, time and date is shown when the task is scheduled. If the notification is delivered; i want it to say ‘Time’s up’

Comment: looks like [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Please explain more context.

Comment: Is there any method to know if a certain notification(using UUID) is delivered or not. If its delivered than change the UI accordingly.

Comment: you've got [completion closure](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenter/1649508-add), so I do not understand your problem.

Comment: Please give more details about "delivered". Thanks.

Comment: @dfd local notification is triggered. In simplest of terms: 1. You create a notification 2. Set a time for it 3. The time comes 4. Notification is triggered. I want to know if there is a way to know that a particular notification is triggered

Comment: Triggered is way different than delivered. Way. So what kind of code is "triggering" the notification, and why are you concerned that it isn't?